# Manifest and supportedOS

Tags: windows, winapi

I just recently found out about the need for a manifest file so that my native C++ Windows app will properly detect the Windows version.  Previously my app was running under the "Operating System Context" of "Windows Vista", but thanks to the manifest file it now runs under the appropriate context for the OS it's running on.

This has sent me down a rabbit hole to learn more about what "Operating System Context" means, and why I should care about it.  I've been searching for specific information on what happens under the hood and the best page I've found is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711(VS.85).aspx

This page details what the Windows Vista (default) application behavior is, and what behavior you can get if you add Windows 7 support via the manifest file.

Here's my problem; I can't find any information like this for Windows 8, 2012, 10, or 2016.  I read through the Windows Compatibility Cookbook, but it doesn't seem to contain the type of information available in the above link.

What terms should I be searching for?  Is there an up-to-date MSDN page I can bookmark that keeps track of the "Operating System Context" differences?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ken.  I did come across that page before, but it's really high level.  It tells me how to build my manifest file and how to add supported OS's, but it doesn't actually describe what happens if I decide to support an OS.  For example, on the link I posted it goes into very specific details about GetOverlappedResult:  if I have manifest support for Windows 7 I'll get one behavior, and if I use the default of Windows Vista I get another.  These are the low level details I'm trying to discover.

Comment: You are not going to get this.  Microsoft has completely given up on it for Windows 10, it will tell you that it is 8.1 even if you use the supportedOS guid for win10.  They instead want you to rely on them keeping their OS compatible, they know how to do that pretty well.  If something is not supported for some reason, say your program is running on a HoloLens, then they'll let you know about it with an error code.  So only use the supportedOS you actually tested your program on.  The version that *you* can support.

Comment: "*need a manifest file so that my app will properly detect the Windows version*" - you **do not** need a manifest just to get the OS version number. There are several ways to get the version that are not subject to manifestion. Such as [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723418.aspx). But you should use a manifest anyway so Windows knows your app's supported capabilities so Windows can adjust its own behaviors accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer -

Microsoft's page on [Application Manifests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows 8 and Server 2012 has a section on the `SupportedOS` element, which refers readers to the download page for the [Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 Compatibility Cookbook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27416).  This Cookbook also covers Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.  Within this Cookbook, the heading "**App (executable) manifest**" discusses the the Windows features included in Windows 8 and 8.1 (as well as Windows Server 2012 & 2012 R2) which are impacted by the presence or absence of the corresponding supportedOS element.  Search this doc for `supportedOS`, as it is mentioned in other sections as well.

As for Windows 10 (and implicitly Windows Server 2016), the latest Windows Compatibility Cookbook can be read online or downloaded from [this web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-10-introduction).  Unfortunately, this latest Cookbook does not go into the details of the specific Windows features that are new or impacted by the supportedOS element for Windows 10.  But many of the various behavior changes or compatibility issues with Windows 10 are discussed here.